# Microsoft Graph giving an error: Authentication Challenge is required

Tags: sdk, microsoft-graph-api

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UploadExcel(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        //Check File code here//


        DriveItem item = null;
        string Secret1 = "secret";
        string Client1 = "clientid";
        string Tenant1 = "tenantid";
        IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(Client1)
        .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant1)
        .WithRedirectUri("uri")
        .WithClientSecret(Secret1)            
        .Build();

        AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider1 = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider1);            
        using (Stream file1 = upload.InputStream)
        {
            try
            {
                item = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["id_of_a_file"]
                .Content
                .Request()
                .PutAsync<DriveItem>(file1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle Exception
            }
        }
        if (item == null)
        {
            //Tell user
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ActionName");
    }
```

**Also Redirect URI is always null no matter what I do.** 
I have searched elsewhere but could not find a solution. This is a Web application. User login is handled by us. Users upload files to Company's OneDrive Account. All the necessary permissions and admin consent are granted. Still error is not resolved.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Hello Amruta, are you still looking for help on this question ?